# When user has not installed the app in android, Firebase deeplink parameter not receiving?

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking

I have integrate deeplink in android with url parameters and when app is already installed and when user click it will get the url parameter correctly and redirect to the correct activity. I have declare following code in manifest.

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="xxxxx.app.goo.gl"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When user is not installed the app and when click the deeplink it redirect to the google play. After installing the app from google play and open, App won't receive the url parameter.
Why is app not receiving url parameters from google play?

Comment: Show the code in you Activity that should run when link is triggered. Is this worked in debug mode when installed via Android studio?

Comment: yes. It is working in debug mode without issue. Also if app already installed when click the link it redirect to correct activity.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?